# Scale Text-Annotations according to Map/Composer-Scale

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, annotation, qgsmapcanvas

Is there a way to set the size of the QGIS Text Annotations to map units so that they get resized when I choose different scales?

I wrote a litte script as a workaround which scales the annotations in the QGIS canvas so that they get smaller when I zoom out.

Screenshot: **annotations at target scale:**
[image]

Screenshot: **smaller annotations when zoomed out:**

[image]

**That's the script I use in the QGIS console:**

```
from qgis.gui import QgsTextAnnotationItem

def scale_annotations():
    target_extent=10000
    current_scale=iface.mapCanvas().scale()
    scale_factor=target_extent/current_scale
    all_annotations=[]
    for item in iface.mapCanvas().items():
        if isinstance( item, QgsTextAnnotationItem ):
            all_annotations.append(item)
    #print all_annotations
    for i in all_annotations:
            curr_scale=i.scale()
            i.setScale(scale_factor)
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

try:
    iface.mapCanvas().extentsChanged.disconnect()
except:
    print "kein disconnect"

iface.mapCanvas().extentsChanged.connect(scale_annotations)
```

But this of course won't scale the annotations in the MapComposer if I want to print multiple layouts with different scales.

Screenshot: **annotations too large in PrintComposer:**
[image: Annotations too large in PrintComposer]

So is there a way to get the annotations scale in Canvas and MapComposer depending on the chosen scale?